# Bitcoin ETF - Press releases

Tags: news-coverage, bitcoin-etf

On 11th of March 2017 the [U.S. Securities and Exchange Commision](https://www.sec.gov/index.htm) will decide whether the *Bitcoin Exchange Traded Fund (ETF)* will be approved or not.

The decision will almost certainly have massive influence on the market as soon as the first press release gets published. So the question is where the first official and reliable statement on the outcome of the decision will be published. The SEC homepage has a [RSS feed for press releases](https://www.sec.gov/news/pressreleases). However it is not certain that the outcome will be published there first. Are there any other reliable services / official news pages where news like this may be released first?

Answer (score -1):

I have a news feed from https://news.bitcoin.com/ . It sends me news articles in a pop-up window similar to Facebook. I'm assuming that they'll know as soon as the decision occurrs.
For the moment I'm in a watch and see, I'd like to buy more but at what price. The BTCs I now own were bought much lower. If the ETF decision is positive we may never see lower again, if negative or ambiguous who knows where the price will go. Down I suppose, in which case I'll buy more when it settles.